# Environment variable and function argument

Tags: bash, environment-variables, arguments

I have a collection of bash functions that include a verbosity level option.  According to the set value, different levels of outputs are generated.  The verbosity is local to each function.

But I also have environment variables.  One of them also specifies a verbosity  level.  It is a global verbosity tool specifically implemented to affect new terminal shells.  If the environment variable is used and set to level 1, a summary of terminal commands available is printed.

Suppose a function is called with a verbosity positional argument, whilst the environment variable is also set, what would most users expect the behavior to be?  To enforce the local verbosity setting, or to use the environment variable level?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us some actual code. We can't help you understand the behavior of code we cannot see. Anything and everything could happen, depending o exactly how you use the variable and how the functions read it and how they're run etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are not subshells. Any changes you make to variables in the function will propagate unless you append them with `local`

You can make a function a subshell by wrapping it in parenthesis `()`

In the example `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/env bash

function amiasubshell {
    DISPLAY=$1
    echo amiasubshell: $DISPLAY
}

function nobuticanfakeit {
    local DISPLAY=$1
    echo nobuticanfakeit: $DISPLAY
}

echo main: $DISPLAY
amiasubshell :2
echo main: $DISPLAY
(amiasubshell :5)
echo main: $DISPLAY
nobuticanfakeit :28
echo main: $DISPLAY
```

The first instance of `amiasubshell` changes the value moving forward in the main body. The second instance does not because it is a subshell. The instance of `nobuticanfakeit` only changes the value in the context of the function because it is a `local` variable:

```
main: :0
amiasubshell: :2
main: :2
amiasubshell: :5
main: :2
nobuticanfakeit: :28
main: :2
```

Comment: I understand that.  The question is about something else.  Suppose I have a local verbosity `vb` and a global verbosity `gvb`.  And one calls a function using the local verbosity,  but ho also has the global verbosity `gvb` enabled to same other level.  Would users expect the function to use the global value level in `gvb` or still continue using the local value `vb`?

Comment: Having some random functions that don't respect the global verbosity level is counter intuitive.

Comment: Which answers an important question as I do not want things counter intuitive to users.